# Google Distance Matrix API Restrictions

Tags: google-maps-api-3, licensing

**Why does Google restrict the use of the JavaScript Distance Matrix API so that it can only be used if you display the data on a Google Map?**

From the [Distance Matrix API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

> Use of the Distance Matrix API must relate to the display of information on a Google Map; for example, to determine origin-destination pairs that fall within a specific driving time from one another, before requesting and displaying those destinations on a map. Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a Google map is prohibited.

I've written a simple bookmark scriptlet for personal use that allows me to select an address and click it and it then displays the driving distance and time to several points of interest. In order to comply with this seemingly arbitrary restriction, I will now have to use more of Google's resources displaying a map that I don't want to see!

Anybody know why they would have this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to licensing restrictions between Google and the data providers.

Comment: Makes sense. Will go and add the map.